# Why wouldn't this countdown timer show on my mobile?

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have some Javascript that is basically a countdown timer:

```
<script>
var clockRunning = false;
var clockPlaceholder = document.getElementById("clock-placeholder");
var targetDate;
var clock;

function updateClock() {
    var cd = countdown(targetDate, null, countdown.DAYS | countdown.HOURS | countdown.MINUTES | countdown.SECONDS, 4);
    clockPlaceholder.innerHTML = cd.toString();
    if (targetDate.getTime() < (new Date()).getTime()) {
        endCountdown();
    }
}

function startCountdown() {
    if (clockRunning == false) {
        var h, m, s;
        // setup target Date object
        var now = new Date(); // console.debug(now.toString());
        var laravelTime = '{{ $auction->endtime }}';
        targetDate = new Date(laravelTime);
        // start clock
        clock = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
        clockRunning = true;
    }
}

function endCountdown() {
    clockPlaceholder.innerHTML = "Auction Ended"
    clearInterval(clock);
    clockRunning = false;
}
</script>
```

This line: `var laravelTime = '{{ $auction->endtime }}';` just gets the endtime from the DB.

Anyway, it works perfectly on my computer but when I browse to the page on my mobile phone (iOS) it doesn't appear at all. Neither Safari nor Chrome shows it.

I'm quite new to `js`. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you calling `startCountdown`?

Comment: when testing on your mobile phone, is the application on your own machine still?

Comment: The application is live on a dev server. I call `startCountdown` at the start of the `<body>` like this: `<body onload="startCountdown">` @RobM.

Comment: Can you put up a jsfiddle or similar? I suspect it's not working because you are not using an onready or ready statement, and when your JS runs, the clock-placeholder does not yet exist on the page, but need more code to be sure.